# Dell laptop CPU temperature at 86°C while doing nothing ... and so fan at full speed

Tags: 20.04, dell, fan, inspiron, sensors

I  have a brand new Dell Inspiron 5000 series.

I put Ubuntu 20.04 on a live USB key and run it.

The problem is that the fan is at highest speed all the time even when doing nothing ...

After trying many things, it seems that the problem is that temperature is high (86°C) even if doing nothing and fan at full speed, so fan never stops.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        4089 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +86.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +67.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +76.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +86.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          17.55 V  
curr1:       303.00 mA
```

**Is there a problem with sensors, cpus, Ubuntu or ... ???**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ top

top - 01:36:23 up  1:44,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.15, 0.17
Tasks: 272 total,   1 running, 271 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15737.6 total,   7364.2 free,   2135.4 used,   6237.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  12523.8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
   5636 ubuntu    20   0 5772320 409312 144436 S   1.3   2.5   8:20.47 gnome-+ 
   6713 ubuntu    20   0 3737612 442272 164944 S   1.3   2.7   3:11.24 MainTh+ 
   1524 root      20   0    2540    728    660 S   0.3   0.0   0:00.44 acpid   
   4842 ubuntu     9 -11 3589316  20996  15976 S   0.3   0.1   0:05.32 pulsea+ 
  23242 root      20   0   28920   5120   4348 S   0.3   0.0   0:01.25 tclsh   
  25024 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:02.38 kworke+ 
  27310 ubuntu    20   0 2752508 238796 156888 S   0.3   1.5   0:16.59 Web Co+ 
  28349 ubuntu    20   0   20600   4048   3248 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.01 top     
      1 root      20   0  169184  13292   8496 S   0.0   0.1   0:12.23 systemd
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Ubuntu 20.10 in place of Ubuntu 20.04

```
Details of the PC :
Inspiron 15 5000 Séries 5502
11th Generation Intel(R) Core(TM)i7-1165G7 Processor (12MB Cache, up to 4.7 GHz)
```